# How to apply CSS class to HTML Action Link in Razor

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, razor, actionlink

I have got:

`<p><a class="btn btn-default" href="~/Person">List of Cients &raquo;</a></p>`

I would like to replace it with HTML Action Link but don't change visual style.

I want to get to `Index` Action of `PersonController`:

public class PersonController : Controller
    {
        private PersonContext db = new PersonContext();

```
    // GET: Person
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.Persons.ToList());
    }
}
```

How the `@Html.ActionLink(...)` should look like.

EDIT:

I tried:

```
   <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="~/Person">List of Cients &raquo;</a></p>
        @Html.ActionLink("List of Clients &raquo", "Index", "Person", new { @class = "btn btn-default" })
```

There is the problem with: `&raquo;` ActionLink does not renders preetty arrow.

EDIT2:

Tried this with no result: `@Html.ActionLink("List of Clients " + HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("&raquo"), "Index", "Person", new { @class = "btn btn-default" })`

EDIT:
Both don't work.

```
  <p> @Html.ActionLink("List of Clients »", "Index", "Person", new { @class = "btn btn-default" })</p>
       <p> @(Html.ActionLink("List of Clients »", "PersonController/Index", new { @class = "btn btn-default" }));
```

First gives right style but when I click I get `length=6` in the link.
Second does not have style and links to: `http://localhost:17697/Home/PersonController/Index?class=btn%20btn-default`

**ANSWER: This one works:**

`<p> @Html.ActionLink("List of Clients »", "Index", "Person", null, new { @class = "btn btn-default" })</p>`

Answer (score 2):

`@(Html.ActionLink("Title", "/PersonController/Index", new { @class = "myCssClass" }));`

Here's a link for reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492124(v=vs.108).aspx

Comment: &raquo; is not understandable by actionLink

The deal is that there was preetty `>>` in orignal link:
 `<p><a class="btn btn-default" href="~/Person">List of Cients &raquo;</a></p>`|||
        `@Html.ActionLink("List of Clients &raquo", "Index", "Person", new { @class = "btn btn-default" })`

Comment: So did this work ?..I understood your question now...you should mention it in the question then. you asked for class in the question

Comment: They don't work. Please look at the last edit in OP.

Comment: This one works: `<p> @Html.ActionLink("List of Clients »", "Index", "Person", null, new { @class = "btn btn-default" })</p>`

Comment: you should really modify your question, asking about html characters codes in text part of actionlink, instead of asking for class. It's confusing for other people.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this, it will work

```
 <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Person")">
    <button class="btn btn-default">
        List of Cients &raquo;
    </button>
    </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
@Html.ActionLink("ButtonText", "Action","Controller", new {@class="btn btn-default"})
```

it's what worked for me.

NB. the `new {@class="btn btn-default"}` goes after the 3rd comma.

Answer (score 0):

```
<pre> 
<p>I will display &#187;</p>
 <div>
        @Ajax.ActionLink("Contact " + HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("&#187;"),
                   "_PartialEmployeeIndex", "Employee",
                        new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "divToUpdate" }, 
                   new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })
    </div>
</pre>
```